# Geometric mean of distances between a point on an ellipse and its foci

Tags: geometry

I just encountered this problem in physics:

> a particle describes an ellipse about a centre of force at the focus;
>   show that, at any point of its path, the angular velocity about the
>   other focus varies inversely as the square of the normal at the point.

When I solved for the equation of angular velocity about the other focus, it came out to be inversely proportional to the product of the distance of the point from the foci. I was not able to proceed as I could not find any relation between the aforementioned quantity and the normal to that point.

I would be glad if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions showing no effort tend to be closed or voted down. What have you tried? Write the equation of an ellipse, find the foci, find the distances, write the geometric mean.

Comment: I just wanted to know whether there was any relation between the geometric mean of the distance between an arbitrary point on an ellipse and its foci and the normal to that point

Comment: The geometric mean is a number, the normal is a line: what kind of relation do you have in mind?

Comment: Geometric mean requires either a finite set, or the set should come with a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)). That measure would be similar to a probability distribution when sampling the set of points on the conic. Do you have any specific measure in mind?

Comment: @AlfredMathew this might help? In your case B,C are the foci, A is the point on the ellipse. The angle bisector is the normal.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem

Comment: this is the question:     a particle describes an ellipse about a centre of force at the focus;show that,at any point of its path,the angular velocity about the other focus varies inversely as the square of the normal at the point?

Comment: when i solved for the equation of angular velocity about the other focus,it came out to be inversely proportional to the product of the distance of the point from the foci

Comment: i found out this question from a book written by s l loney..so i thought maybe normal was something that mathematicians might know

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=(0,-c)$ and $B=(0,c)$ be the foci of the ellipse of equation $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$, with $c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$. If $P=(x,y)$ is a point on the ellipse, the normal line at $P$ is the bisector of $\angle APB$ and it intersects line $AB$ at some point $N=(x_N,0)$.

From the angle bisector theorem we have: $PA:PB=NA:NB$, that is:
$$
(x_N+c)^2\big((x-c)^2+y^2\big)=(x_N-c)^2\big((x+c)^2+y^2\big).
$$ 
Inserting here $y^2=b^2-(b^2/a^2)x^2$ one obtains
$$
x(x_N^2+c^2)-x_N\left({c^2\over a^2}x^2+a^2\right)=0,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
\left(x_N-{c^2\over a^2}x\right)(xx_N-a^2)=0.
$$
This gives $x_N=(c^2/a^2)x$ (the other solution must be discarded because $|a^2/x|\ge a$) and consequently: 
$$
PN^2=b^2-{b^2c^2\over a^4}x^2.
$$
On the other hand one can compute:
$$
PA\cdot PB=a^2-{c^2\over a^2}x^2,
$$
so that:
$$
PN^2=b^2-{b^2\over a^2}(a^2-PA\cdot PB)={b^2\over a^2}PA\cdot PB.
$$
We have then:
$$
\sqrt{PA\cdot PB}={a\over b}PN.
$$

Comment: Very interesting result but a section of your proof is a little elliptic :) when you say "From the angle bisector theorem one _readily_ gets...". Could you a little expand this part ? Besides, I am striken by the fact that we see in your last formula, for $a \approx b$ a similarity with Cassinian ovals defined by the constraint : **product** of distances to 2 fixed points = const.

Comment: I added some more details.